Semiconductor device testing
I'm a graduate engineer who's recently started a job testing silicon wafers consisting of both power MOSFETs or diodes and some IGBTs.
Unfortunately there's little in terms of support and training relating to the role.
How are tests are setup for these mosfets/IGBTs and their purpose? These test systems have some complex looking circuitry just to interface between the test unit and the device, which I again struggle to understand.
Some of the more complex tests are the UIL, CIL, dynamic RDson to name a few.

A very broad question.  Sounds like you're testing bare die, at the wafer level, correct? And are you looking for a rough "is it working" kind of test, or are you interested in parametric testing?

Some manufacturers will provide test setups in the data sheets or another documents to show how they tested the MOSFETs. There should be also available technical articles and research articles available to show how to test these devices.
For example searching dynamic RDSon yields this article that explains how you can test for a GAN transistor which should be fairly similar set up for other types of transistors.
https://eepower.com/technical-articles/dynamic-on-resistance-measurement-techniques-for-gan-power-transistors/

What Voltage Spike said, the spec sheets provide at least an abbreviated explanation of test conditions.
The SUPPLIER of the test equipment (or parts of the test equipment) usually has technical notes about using it. In addition they may provide some technical discussion- because after all, they want to sell the stuff.
Be aware that sales engineers are typically not the brightest.
